# how can I force the source file implement definition for a header file

Tags: c, gcc

below is the code:

```
//test.h
...
extern int globalVariable;
...
```

```
//test.c

#include "test.h"
...
int globalVariable = 2020;
...
```

```
//main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h" 

int main()
{
   printf("Value is %d", globalVariable);
}
```

let's say in a scenario, there are hundreds of variables are declared in `test.h` and `globalVariable` is just one of them.

since there are two many variables, I easily makes a typo error in `test.c` as:

```
#include "test.h"

int globalVariables = 2020;   //extra 's' in the name which contradicts the declaration of its counterpart in test.h
```

if I compile(only compile,not linking them) `test.c`, `test.h` and `main.c`, it compiles and shows no error. the unresolved error will only occur when linker involved in the linking stage.

But in a large application, I might just write some modules without the need of linking all existing to an executable file, so it would be better the compiler throw an error in the compile stage to indicate the error so I can correct them asap, so how can I let the compiler force the source file implement definition for a header file?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the preprocessor

**test.h**:

```
#ifndef TEST_C_IMPLEMENTATION
#define DEFINE_AND_INIT_VARIABLE(type, name, value) \
    extern type name;
#else
#define DEFINE_AND_INIT_VARIABLE(type, name, value) \
    type name = value;
#endif

DEFINE_AND_INIT_VARIABLE(int, globalVariable, 2020);
```

**test.c**:

```
#define TEST_C_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "test.h"
```

This technique can be taken even further - there are small utility libraries that are shipped as a single include file; you're just to set a macro in *one* of the translation units to force the implementation to be compiled in there.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `extern int globalVariable;` says that the variable exists *somewhere*, but not necessarily in the current translation unit.  So any source file that includes the header containing this declaration will know that the variable exists without needing the full definition.

When you then get to the linking stage is when you'll get the error regarding `glovalVariable` being undefined.  Since the variables is declared in test.h, convention would dictate that the definition would be in test.c.  Upon inspecting that file, you would then find that no such variable exists and could then either add it or find the typo and fix it.

Comment: @dbusg so I won't be alterted of the typo until I linker files?

Comment: @dbush is right. Your question is around implementing a coding convention. If you would like, you can implement this check as a script and execute it as part of your makefile (or build process). For eg: A script that pulls the list of extern declarations from .h files and extern definitions from .c files and finds entries in .h list that aren't in the .c list. Be warned that you may have to implement a mini C parser to handle extern declarations and variable definitions. If you do intend going down that path, try ANTLR that can generate the parser from the C grammar.